# how to add web view in list view with example

Tags: android, listview

can anybody tell how to add web view in list view in android give example

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a CustomListview and add a Webview to your custom layout.

btw . For what purpose are you trying to use Webview on a listview. If it is to load HTMl tags you can try using

```
Textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("You HTML String"));
```